# IOS: Possible to Sort on property of managedObject property with NSFetchResults Controller

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Using an NSFetchedResultsController, is it possible to sort (using NSSortDescriptor) on a property of the managedObject as opposed to an attribute in the sql database?

My entity has the following two attributes:

```
firstname
lastname
```

I have a "property", `fullName`, that combines these into a single name.  I could show you the code but it's pretty standard.

Not sure it's a full blown property. It's signature is:

```
-(NSString*)fullName;
```

Question: Can I sort on the property `fullName` as opposed to the attributes?

This is what the sortDescriptor looks like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor17 =[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"fullName" ascending:YES];
```

When I try to do this I am getting an error that the property fullName is not found in the sqlLite database as follows:.

> error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
>    , keypath fullName not found
>   in entity  with userInfo of (null)
>   CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:
>    , keypath fullName not found
>   in entity  with userInfo of (null)

Thanks for any insights or suggestions.

Comment: You can't, but you provide an array of sort descriptors to the fetch request, so you can sort by first name and then by last name (or by last name and then by first name if you prefer).  This should have the same effect as sorting by full name)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work perfectly as not all contacts have both a first and last. It groups all the listings with only a first, then those with only a last and then those with both rather than intermingling.

Comment: It's funny cause I was able to get NSPredicate to search by fullName property.  But I guess NSSortDescriptor doesn't support it?

Comment: I think `NSSortDescriptor` pushes the sorting down to the underlying backing store.  You probably just need to create `fullName` as an attribute and populate it; the extra storage is probably not significant.

Comment: Yes. Trying to avoid migration of data model. But does not seem to be a simple workaround.